# bootstrap modal is covered and not displayed correctly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Since I've included some style sheets and java script my bootstrap modal is not working correctly anymore. It seems that the div with the "modal-backdrop" class lies in front of the div with the "modal" class. And the modal content is only visible in a small scrollable div.
You can see the problem when clicking on the button: http://tamara-alber.de/meseck/bootstrap/index.html

I don't know why it is messed up. I can't solve the problem. Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Scrolling Nav - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800"></link>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic"></link>

<link type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Animate CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Lightbox CSS -->
<link type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="css/dark.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Scrolling Nav JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ekko-lightbox.js"></script>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
            // delegate calls to data-toggle="lightbox"
            $(document).delegate('*[data-toggle="lightbox"]', 'click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return $(this).ekkoLightbox({
                    always_show_close: true
                });
            });

        });

    new WOW().init();

    $(window).stellar({ horizontalScrolling: false });

</script>
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Frederick Meseck</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Test?</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Test</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#pricing">Test</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#angebot">Test</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Test</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Intro Section -->
<section id="intro" class="intro-section" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 wow animated bounceInDown">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>



<!-- Wofür Section -->
<section id="about" class="about-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row wow animated zoomIn" data-wow-duration="700ms">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="special-heading dark-special">Test?</h1>
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Test</h3>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</section>

<!-- Erfahren Sie mehr -->
<section class="technology-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row wow animated zoomIn">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Button</button>
                <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title special-heading dark-special">Features und Technologie</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="featurebox margin-btm-30">
                                    <i class="fa fa-html5"></i>
                                    <div class="featuretext">
                                        <h4>Test</h4>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- END OF FEATUREBOX 1 -->

                            </div><!-- END OF COL FEATURE BOX1 -->
                            <div class="col-md-4 margin-btm-30">
                                <img src="images/frederick_meseck_angebot_starter_plus" class="img-responsive featureimg" alt="">
                            </div><!-- END OF COL FEATURE BOX2 -->
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="featureboxleft margin-btm-30 ">
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                    <div class="featuretext">
                                        <h4>Test</h4>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- END OF FEATUREBOX 1 -->

                            </div><!-- END OF COL FEATURE BOX3 -->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>





<script type="text/javascript"src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Comment: Move the markup for your modal outside of those `col-`s and `rows`. Try Placing it just before the closing `</body>` and it will work correctly

Comment: Modal isn't being activated properly possibly due to a plugin conflict? It should be getting appended to body by bootstrap but it isn't

Comment: @charlietfl That's not how it works. Bootstrap doesn't append the modal. It displays it where it is placed in the markup.

Comment: @SexyTurnip ok, bad assumption on my part

Comment: @charlietfl: I have solved the problem with your solution. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)...

> **Modal markup placement** Always try to place a modal's HTML code in a
>   top-level position in your document to avoid other components
>   affecting the modal's appearance and/or functionality.

As stated above, if you move your markup so that it is no longer nested within other elements, just before the closing `</body>` for example, it will work as you expect.